# Is it important to define both ends of relationships/FKs with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, foreign-keys

Using EntityFramework, I'm curious if there is a performance gain when you specify both ends of a foreign key verses only one. Suppose I have a table that is used by most other tables, e.g. a lookup table. Let's say this table, `LookupValue`, has 20 incoming foreign keys and another table, `User`, is on the other end of one of those foreign keys via the column `TypeId`.

```
LookupValue
------------------
Id       INT     <--\
Values   NVARCHAR   |
                    |
User                | FK_User_NameValue
------------------  |
Id       INT        |
TypeId   INT     <--/
```

Using code-first I define these tables as follows:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<LookupValue>()
    .ToTable("LookupValue")
    .HasKey(o => o.Id);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<User>()
    .ToTable("User")
    .HasKey(o => o.Id)
    .HasRequired(o => o.Type)
    .WithMany(o => o.UsersOfThisType)
    .HasForeignKey(o => o.TypeId);
```

*My questions are*...

- Is the `WithMany...HasForeignKey` portion necessary or helpful to EF to allow it to better generate queries between these two tables?
- Do navigation properties have any role other than navigation via code?
- Or would EF know about this foreign key relationship if I didn't specify the other end of the relationship?

E.g.:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<User>()
    .ToTable("User")
    .HasKey(o => o.Id)
    .HasRequired(o => o.Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only need to traverse from User to LookupValue, you can just have the accessor property in User.  No need to have an ICollection<User> in the LookupValue object if you don't need to find all users that refer to a LookupValue.

```
public class LookupValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public LookupValue Type { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will generate a foreign key from Users to LookupValues via the TypeId attribute in Users. I think that's all you should need for performant traversing from Users to LookupValue.

[image: SQL Server Management Studio foreign key properties window]

Comment: Also, side note: you probably don't even need to override OnModelCreating and use Fluent API in this simple case.  Using the classes here Entity Framework was smart enough to infer which attribute was the foreign key since Type was the accessor and a TypeId attribute was present.